# Angular Firebase: Cant get current user after page refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve a document in Firestore with data for the current user(player) of a game; I am able to get the document, however as soon as I refresh the page, the `firebase.auth().currentUser` becomes null. The users are signed in anonymously if that makes a difference. I have tried changing the persistence, which did not seem to change anything

In my gameService.ts file:

```
private getCurrentPlayer(gameId: string){
    return this.afs.doc(`games/${gameId}/players/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`);
}
```

In my component.ts file:

```
constructor(private gameService: GameService, private route: ActivatedRoute) 
{
    gameService.currentPlayer.valueChanges().subscribe(user =>{
      console.log(user)
      this.currentPlayer = user;
    });
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that `currentUser` will not be set the second the app launches after refresh and starts constructing things in preparation for booting. It won't be set until a few ticks of the clock pass, during which Firebase figures out that someone is logged in and processes it. Your code needs to take this lag into account. For instance, you might want to move the code out of your constructor into a method which is triggered in the `ngOnInit`, just as an example.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks I created a sleep method to delay calling `getCurrentPlayer()`, which worked however this approach seems kinda sloppy. Would there be any better ways to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use localStorage for persistance storing:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', user)
```

Then if you want use user obj, you can do like this

```
myUser = localStorage.getItem('user')
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
return this.angularFireAuth.authState
  .pipe(
    filter(user => !!user),
    switchmap(user => this.afs.doc(`games/${gameId}/players/${user.uid}`));
```

The observable can be set up at any time, including in your constructor, but will not fire until there is a recognized user, at which point it will give you the doc you want for that user.